# subprocess.PIPE not working in django model

Tags: python, django, django-models, subprocess

So I have this model in which there is `isRunning` property. When it is set to `True` it spawns a subprocessing instance and saves it to `subprocessObject` . It looks like this.

```
class Monitor(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=143)
    # Some other stuff

    CommandToExecute = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default="python -c print('HelloWorld')")
    subprocessObject = None

    @property
    def isRunning(self):
        return False

    @isRunning.getter
    def isRunning(self):
        if self.subprocessObject is None or self.subprocessObject.poll() is None:
            return False
        return True

    @isRunning.setter
    def isRunning(self, value):
        if value is True and self.isRunning is False:
            self.subprocessObject = subprocess.Popen(self.CommandToExecute.split(" "), stdout=sys.stdout, stdin=sys.stdin, shell=True)
        elif value is False and self.isRunning is True:
            self.subprocessObject.stdin.close()
            self.subprocessObject.stdout.close()
            self.subprocessObject.terminate()
            self.subprocessObject == None

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name
```

For now it starts an file that prints something each second or so with `flush=True`.

The problem is that there is an error looking like this:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

When I changed `subprocess.PIPE` to `sys.stdout` and when I started the subprocess in a view it worked as expected so it's probably problem with `subprocess.PIPE` in models?

Should I start the process in a view or is there an solution?

Comment: When will `self.isRunning is None` ever be true?  The getter for this property only returns False or True.

Comment: @jasonharper It's a mistake, sorry